# Does every set with at least two or more elements admit a fixed-point free self-bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume $X$ is a set with at least two elements. Is there a bijection from $X$ to $X$ such that for every $x\in X$ , $f(x) \ne x$ ?

Comment: Relevant keyword: [derangement](http://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_derangements).

Comment: "more than two" $\ne$ "at least two"

Comment: what if X is uncountable?

Comment: @M.Vinay Inasmuch as the question is trivial for finite sets, I suppose the OP is interested in the case of infinite sets. I believe the Axiom of Choice is needed.

Comment: @bof So I gather from the OP's comment. The "at least two elements" in the question made me think only finite sets were of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, at least if you allow some choice.

Let $\mathcal T$ be the collection of bijections $f\colon U\to V$ where $U,V$ are disjoint subsets of $X$. Then $\mathcal T$ is not empty (it contains $\operatorname{id}_\emptyset$) and is inductively ordered in the obvious way (i.e., by letting $(f\colon U\to V)\ge (f'\colon U'\to V')$ iff $U'\subseteq U$ and $V'\subseteq V$ and $f|_{U'}=f'$). Hence by Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal element $m\colon A\to B$ of $\mathcal T$.

- If $A\cup B=X$ we are done as we can let $$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}m(x)&x\in A\\m^{-1}(x)&x\in B\end{cases}$$
- If $X\setminus(A\cup B)$ has at least two elements $a,b$, we can extend $m$ to $\tilde m\colon (A\cup \{a\})\to (B\colon \{b\})$ by mapping $a$ to $b$. As this would contradict the maximality of $m$, this case does not occur
- If $X\setminus(A\cup B)=\{c\}$ we can proceed as follows: **As $X$ has at least two elements, $A$ and $B$ cannot be empty.**  Pick $a\in A$ and define
  $$ \phi(x)=\begin{cases}m(x)&x\in A\setminus\{a\}\\
  m^{-1}(x)&x\in B\\
  m(a)&x=c\\
  c&x=a\end{cases} $$ and that is our bijection.

Comment: Maybe it is slightly simpler to use Zorn's lemma to get a maximal collection of pairwise disjoint two-element subsets. From that you get a partition into sets of size two or three, with at most one set being of size three.

Answer (score 3):

Outline: Let $X$ be an infinite set, and let $Y$ be a set disjoint from $X$ which has the same cardinality as $X$. Then it is a standard result of ZFC that $X\cup Y$ has the same cardinality as $X$. Now it is easy to find a bijection from $X\cup Y$ to $X\cup Y$ that has no fixed point. Just map any element of $X$ to its "twin" in $Y$, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a counterexample in the absence of the axiom of choice.

Suppose that $X$ is [strictly amorphous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set), and suppose that $f:X\to X$ is a bijection. Since $X$ is [Dedekind finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set), there is no injection from $\Bbb N$ to $X$, and therefore for each $x\in X$ there is a least integer $n_x\in Z^+$ such that $f^{n_x}(x)=x$. It follows that each orbit under $f$ is finite. The orbits under $f$ partition $X$, so infinitely many of them are of size $1$, and $f$ has infinitely many fixed points.

Comment: @ArshGh: You’re welcome.